# Last digit of the power of 2 numbers without performing the operation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to find the units digit of a number raised to another number without calculating the result of the operation, i.e 5**7 = 78125, so I want to write a function that returns 5 as the last digit of the operation.

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/finding-the-last-digit-of-a-power/

Comment: More curious about why than how.

Comment: It's used when dealing with large numbers !

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://www.justquant.com/numbertheory/units-digit-of-a-number-raised-to-power/) offer a simple algorithm that explains how to deal with such problem.

> Identify the units digit in the base ‘x’ and call it say ‘l’. {For
>   example, If x = 24, then the units digit in 24 is 4. Hence l = 4.}
>   Divide the exponent ‘y’ by 4. If the exponent y is exactly divisible
>   by 4. i.e, y leaves a remainder 0 when divided by 4. Then, the units
>   digit of pow(x,y) is 6, if l = 2,4,6,8. the units digit of  pow(x,y) is 1,
>   if l =3,7,9. If y leaves a non-zero remainder r, when divided by 4
>   (i.e y = 4k + r). Then, the units digit of  pow(x,y) = pow(I,r) .

A basic implementation of this algorithm :

```
function getLastDigit(x, y) {
  const I = x % 10;
  const r = y % 4;
  if (r === 0) {
    if (I === 2 || I === 4 || I === 6 || I === 8) {
      return 6 % 10;
    }
    if (I === 3 || I === 7 || I === 9) {
      return 1 % 10;
    }
  }
  return I ** r % 10;
}
console.log(getLastDigit(2019, 2020));
```